# How to make the tab bar/nav bar blur effects more clear(transparency)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

As we know that in tab bar/ nav bar if setting translucent to YES will have blur effects turned on when view scroll into this area.

Now I want to implement some blur effects like below in my tab bar:
[image]
Just set translucent to YES won't give me so clear(or say,transparency/strong) tab bar blur effects as above.

After I tried set bar tint color(with opacity) or tab bar background color(with opacity) or tab bar background alpha, I still can't achieve this clear blur effects.

Any one knows how to achieve this in iOS default tab bar/nav bar? Or this is actually a customised tab bar and they add a blur view on top of it. 
Please enlighten me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a custom tab bar using this kind of blurred background. It's probably using a [UIBlurEffect](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBlurEffect_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014531-CH1-SW1) with a UIVisualEffectView.

There are different [UIBlurEffectStyles](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBlurEffect_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBlurEffectStyle) that you can use; they can be light, very light or dark. The one used in the image you posted looks like **UIBlurEffectStyleDark**.

Try this code with any UIView, you'll see.

```
UIBlurEffect * effect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
UIVisualEffectView * viewWithBlurredBackground =
[[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:effect];
[viewWithBlurredBackground setFrame:customViewView.frame];
[customView.frame insertSubview:viewWithBlurredBackground atIndex:0];
```

My idea on how to achieve this tab bar would be to use/make a custom view tab bar and implement the blur yourself with the code above.